# Loss Not Decreasing pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am making a simple CNN without a pooling layer and optimizer (not allowed since its a college assignment). I am using the SVHN dataset. I am using crossentropy loss but loss keeps jumping between 2.305 and 2.306 in 10 epochs. Kindly help.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(Net,self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32,kernel_size=3, padding=1)
    # self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
    self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(
      nn.Flatten(),
      nn.Linear(64*32*32, 10)
    )

def forward(self, x):
    x = (F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
    x = (F.relu(self.conv2(x)))

    x = self.fc1(x)
    return x
net = Net()


criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

for epoch in range(10):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
net.train()
batch_loss_val=0
running_loss = 0.0

for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
    # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
    inputs, labels = data

    # forward + backward
    outputs = net(inputs)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    loss.backward()
    # optimizer.step()

    # print statistics
    running_loss += loss.item()
    if i % 50 == 0:    # print every 50 mini-batches
        print(f'[{epoch + 1}, {i + 1:5d}] loss: {running_loss / 50 :.3f}')
        running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `optimizer.step()` to update the weights. `loss.backward()` is only computing the gradients.

Comment: According to my assignment, i am not allowed an optimizer for this, is there any other way to update the weights?

Comment: @ShashwatGoyal Unfortunately this makes no sense, the optimizer is literally what updates the weights, maybe you misunderstood your assignment or you are meant to implement the same functionality independently?